# Why an empty body tag has two ghost nodes in it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I wrote a function that counts the total number of nodes in the DOM.

```
var nodeCount = 1; 
//1 for the first node, assuming it IS a node
function traverseDom(currentNode) {
  if(nodeCount == 1 || !(currentNode.nextSibling)){
    if(currentNode.firstChild){
    nodeCount += 1;
//console.log(currentNode.firstChild.nodeType);
    traverseDom(currentNode.firstChild);
    }
  }else{
     if(currentNode.nextSibling){
      nodeCount += 1;
      traverseDom(currentNode.nextSibling);
     }
  }
return nodeCount;
}
console.log(traverseDom(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]));
```

The function takes a root node as the argument, walks the DOM from that point and returns the number of nodes. It works for the other nodes but when I pass the `body` element, even if there is no whitespace between the tag, the function always returns 3. Where are these 2 invisible nodes coming from?
Here is the HTML structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: you can `console.log()` nodes too. The browser console is not restricted to strings.

Comment: Text nodes! Line endings and whitespace can count as nodes.

Comment: @evolutionxbox but there is no line ending or space. It's just `<body></body>` not `<body> </body>`. For instance if I place a `<div> </div>` within it and pass `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]` as the argument, it will return 2. The element node (div) and the text node (space). Why is the result different for `body`?

Comment: When I execute `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].firstChild.nodeType);` it logs 1 to the console. Which means, not only does the `<body></body>` node have a first child, but also it is of type 1 (Element), not 3 (Text) (see more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

Comment: JSBin automatically inserts a script element inside the body, for live-reloading. This may account for the "ghost" elements you're seeing.

Comment: @evolutionxbox this should be posted as answer